# Sklearn - Can we use cross validation and batch training in same model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

Is it possible to train a sklearn random forest model by using k-fold cross validation by giving batch by batch the input set? Because I have some problems with a memory issue. I can not fit all training data at a time. Besides, I want to use cross-validation (not train test split). Is there any example of usage for that?

Update: I found [this website](https://spell.ml/blog/getting-oriented-in-the-rapids-distributed-ml-ecosystem-part-2-X68AOxIAACAAacZk) where they present a library to do that. In that, the is an example as follows:

```
from dask_ml.wrappers import Incremental
from dask_ml.datasets import make_classification
import sklearn.linear_model

X, y = make_classification(chunks=25)
est = sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf = Incremental(est, scoring='accuracy')
clf.fit(X, y, classes=[0, 1])
```

However, I can not understand where I give my own X and y data to the model. I do not see where they came from. How can I fit my own train data to the model?

Comment: You have two questions here. Is it how to replace `X` and `y` with your data, or do batch training for a `sklearn` `RandomForestClassifier` object?

Comment: The first one is more crucial for me (how to replace x and y). However, I have also problem with random forest batch training.

Comment: In this case, `X` and `y` is the entire dataset, aka, it has not been split for train, test, and validation. You would pass your training data to the `.fit()` call. Can you please edit the question to show the code that has _your_ data in it, or to clarify what is confusing?

Comment: @wundermahn, in line `X, y = make_classification(chunks=25)` we define X and y. Where we give our own data. Because here there is no relation with our data. This is only as a definition.